# Determining a sequence generation variable

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let

$$
\begin{align}
r_1 &= c + d + \frac{d}{2} + \frac{d}{4} + \dots + \frac{d}{2^n}\\
r_2 &= c + d + \frac{d}{2} + \frac{d}{4} + \dots + \frac{d}{2^n} + \frac{d}{2^{n+1}} \\
r_3 &= c + d + \frac{d}{2} + \frac{d}{4} + \dots + \frac{d}{2^n} + \frac{d}{2^{n+1}} + \frac{d}{2^{n+2}} 
\end{align}
$$

Is it possible to calculate $d$ (or more specifically the limit which is $c+2d$) if $n$ is the only other unknown?

My approach had me taking differences and using logs, but $d$ ended up dropping out.

Comment: I'll adjust that!

Answer (score 0):

First note that

$$r_2-r_1=\frac{d}{2^{n+1}}\;,$$

so that $$\frac1{2^n}=\frac{2(r_2-r_1)}d\;.$$

Then use the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series:

$$\begin{align*}
d+\frac{d}2+\frac{d}4+\ldots+\frac{d}{2^n}&=d\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac12\right)^k\\
&=d\left(2-\frac1{2^n}\right)\\
&=d\left(2-\frac{2(r_2-r_1)}d\right)\\
&=2d-2r_2+2r_1\;,
\end{align*}$$

so $r_1=c+2d-2r_2+2r_1$, and $$d=\frac12(2r_2-r_1-c)\;.$$